# Stick div to top of parent div on scroll

Tags: jquery

This is a variation of the question of sticking a `div` to the top of the page. Instead I need a div to stick to the top of its parent div, which has been set to `overflow: auto`.

http://jsfiddle.net/7F22m/
(Code cobbled from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819842/make-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-and-stop-before-hitting-the-footer).)

`#sticky` should stick to the top of `#wrapper` once it reaches the top of `#wrapper`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191156/jquery-how-to-make-a-fixed-div-scroll-horizontally-after-scrolling-vertically

Answer (score 0):

They're multiple ways of making this work… A bit of guidance:
http://jsfiddle.net/WykZ5/3/

The code above isn't perfect but should be a start. The reason it wasn't working is that the code didn't get launched.

Do you use console.log() to debug? If not Google it. It will help a lot.

Also check out:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

I used mostly used this code as reference:
https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/docs/assets/js/application.js#L61