# Making a fixed element scroll fit to page

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kAAK9/1/

```
<body>
<nav id="mainNav">
    <div id="navCenter">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="navItem" id="home">Home</td>
                <td class="navItem" id="forums">Forums</td>
                <td class="navItem" id="staff">Staff</td>
                <td class="navItem" id="donate">Donate</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h2>Servername</h2>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

If the output window is smaller than 960px; I need a scroll bar to be added at the bottom, How would I do this? I have tried adding overflow properties but have had no luck.

JQUERY Solution: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676131/how-do-i-get-a-fixed-position-div-to-scroll-horizontally-with-the-content-using)

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow-x: scroll
```

apply that to whatever you need a scroll to

Comment: I have added this to the body, This way the body text will scroll when the bar is moved, However since the nav is fixed, it does not scroll.