# Fixing Nav Bar to top of page

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of redesigning a website and I've created a nav bar in CSS3. I would like to permanently fix that bar to the top of the page so that when scrolling it would always be right in front of you at the top.  Here is the code so far:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content: none;
}
/* remember to define focus styles! */
 :focus {
    outline: 0;
}
/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
 table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
/*---------- BODY --------------------------------*/
 body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #e0e0e0;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
/*---------- Wrapper --------------------*/
 nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: #222;
}
ul {
    text-align: right;
}
ul li {
    font: 13px Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -moz-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -ms-transition: padding .05s linear;
    -o-transition: padding .05s linear;
    transition: padding .05s linear;
}
ul li.drop {
    position: relative;
}
ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
ul li a {
    line-height:80px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    height: 80px;
    color: #777;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
ul li a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}
.dropOut .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid white;
    top: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.dropdownContain {
    width: 160px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    /* half of width */
    top: -400px;
}
.dropOut {
    width: 160px;
    background: white;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .1s ease-out;
    transition: all .1s ease-out;
}
.dropOut ul {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
.dropOut ul li {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    padding: 12px 0 10px 15px;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    color: #777;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: background .1s ease-out;
    transition: background .1s ease-out;
}
.dropOut ul li:hover {
    background: #f6f6f6;
}
ul li:hover a {
    color: white;
}
ul li:hover .dropdownContain {
    top: 65px;
}
ul li:hover .underline {
    border-bottom-color: #777;
}
ul li:hover .dropOut {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Also I was wondering how do you fix the links in the nav bar to be bold in CSS3? I tried using font-weight but that didn't seem to work and so I had to go into the HTML and bold each link individually. Any other suggestions on the nav bar would be greatly appreciated but not expected.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
</head>
    <body>
        <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Home</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>About</strong></a></li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#"><strong>Contact</strong></a>

                <div class="dropdownContain">
                        <div class="dropOut">
                            <div class="triangle"></div>                            
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>FAQs</strong></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Custom Drums</strong></a></li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#"><strong>Drum Shows</strong></a>

                <div class="dropdownContain">
                        <div class="dropOut">
                            <div class="triangle"></div>                            
                            <ul>
                                <li><strong>PA Show</strong></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#"><strong>Parts</strong></a>

                <div class="dropdownContain">
                    <div class="dropOut">
                        <div class="triangle"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><strong>Snare</strong></li>
                            <li><strong>Bass and Tom</strong></li>
                            <li><strong>Heads</strong></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Services</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question not clear enough. Could you post an fiddle or atleast a screenshot

Comment: just give it a `position:fixed;top:0;left:0;`

Comment: Please post your nav bar HTML too

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a fixed position div to scroll horizontally with the content? Using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676131/how-do-i-get-a-fixed-position-div-to-scroll-horizontally-with-the-content-using)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anything you want to stay on the page as you scroll should be `position:fixed`

if you want it to stay at the top give it `top:0;left:0`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jtunL29p/)

Comment: Do you need top:0;left:0 to keep at the top of the page? I tried position: fixed without it in JSFIDDLE and it stayed just where I wanted it.

Comment: you don't need it technically, but I'd put it in there just in case.

Comment: Thanks... I was wondering though do you know how to set the nav bar links to bold in CSS3? I tried what Raj suggested but it just didn't work at all. I had to go back to the HTML and bold each individually

Comment: Not at all... It doesn't make them bold. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong part of the coding or IE doesn't recognize it.

Comment: ah IE... I don't know about IE, IE is a pain in the behind

Comment: ah, I did put it in the wrong section of code... Silly me, I should know better

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `position:fixed` and `left:0px; top:0px` to place at top left of screen

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jammycoder/LhjL5s4r/

Comment: I guess I don't need left:0px; top:0px to keep it at the top as when you apply position:fixed, it fixes it to the page where it's currently at which is the top.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing the Nav bar include this:

```
nav
{
     Position:fixed;
}
```

To make links to Bold, try these property values:

```
font-weight: normal|bold|bolder|lighter|number|initial|inherit;
```

Comment: Well it seems it just added it to the wrong section of coding. Once I corrected my mistakes, it worked like a charm. Thanks for your help.